# Swift Error while Unwrapping Optional NSDictionary

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, plist, system-profiler

I am attempting to use the output from the **system_profiler** tool to gather a record of installed applications on the current machine. The following command outputs **XML** in a **plist** format:

```
system_profiler -nospawn SPApplicationsDataType -xml -detailLevel mini
```

and outputs something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>_SPCommandLineArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/sbin/system_profiler</string>
            <string>-nospawn</string>
            <string>SPApplicationsDataType</string>
            <string>-xml</string>
            <string>-detailLevel</string>
            <string>mini</string>
        </array>
        <key>_SPCompletionInterval</key>
        <real>8.4461650252342224</real>
        <key>_dataType</key>
        <string>SPApplicationsDataType</string>
        <key>_detailLevel</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>_items</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>_name</key>
                <string>Terminal</string>
                <key>has64BitIntelCode</key>
                <string>yes</string>
                <key>lastModified</key>
                <date>2014-09-30T21:28:15Z</date>
                <key>obtained_from</key>
                <string>apple</string>
                <key>path</key>
                <string>/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app</string>
                <key>runtime_environment</key>
                <string>arch_x86</string>
                <key>signed_by</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Software Signing</string>
                    <string>Apple Code Signing Certification Authority</string>
                    <string>Apple Root CA</string>
                </array>
                <key>version</key>
                <string>2.5</string>
            </dict>
```

which just goes on to list all of the installed applications on the system.

However, while attempting to assign that data to an `NSDictionary` in order to access the elements, one way or another I end up receiving this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I cannot figure out why this is and every attempt at gathering this information always leads to the error. Here is the current code that I'm attempting to use:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("/Users/Tyler/Documents/data", ofType: "plist")
var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

I've also tried:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("/Users/Tyler/Documents/data", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
```

This of course is after exporting the returned data to its own file, just so I don't have to wait every time for the command to be run. Ideally I would wish to take the output of the command directly with an `NSTask` and receiving the **standardOutput**.

Any information in this matter would be greatly appreciated! I've really come to an impasse with this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you notice that the plist starts with `<array>`, not with `<dict>`? What do you think happens if you read that into `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Regardless, it seems that declaring as NSArray and reading the contents of the file still return the same fatal error.